# Ostream tellp fails on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ostream

I am executing the same code in Windows 10 and in Linux with Qt 5.7 and it only works in Linux. 
I am trying to determine the size of an <s>Ostream</s> IOstream that I just created, so it should be empty. In Linux Size() returns 0, but in Windows it returns -1 because tellp() fails.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <sstream>

    class Foo {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> myOstream;
    std::shared_ptr<std::istream> myIstream;

public:
    Foo::Foo(std::shared_ptr<std::iostream> myIostream)
        : myIstream(std::static_pointer_cast<std::istream>(myIostream))
        , myOstream(std::static_pointer_cast<std::ostream>(myIostream))
    {}

    uint64_t Foo::Size() {
        int ret = 0;

        std::cout << "Before – Fail Flag: " << myOstream->fail() << ", Bad Bit: " << myOstream->bad() << std::endl;

        if (myIstream.get() != nullptr) {
            myIstream->clear();
            auto oldPos = myIstream->tellg();            //returns 0
            myIstream->seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
            ret = static_cast<int>(myIstream->tellg());  //returns 0
            myIstream->seekg(oldPos);
        }

        if (myOstream.get() != nullptr) {
            auto oldPos = myOstream->tellp();           //returns -1
            myOstream->seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
            ret = static_cast<int>(myOstream->tellp()); //returns -1
            myOstream->seekp(oldPos);
        }
            //Fail Flag returns -1, Bad Bit Flag returns 0
        std::cout << "After – Fail Flag: " << myOstream->fail() << ", Bad Bit: " << myOstream->bad() << std::endl;

        return static_cast<uint64_t>(ret);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto myStringStream = std::make_shared<std::stringstream>(
        std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    Foo foo(std::static_pointer_cast<std::iostream>(myStringStream));

    std::cout << "Size: " << foo.Size() << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get `18446744073709551615` as the size since it returns -1 and I convert it to `uint64`. The `Before Fail` and `Bad flag` both return 0. The `After Fail` flag returns 1 and the `Bad flag` returns 0.

<s>I read that it is because the construction of the sentry failed, but I can't figure out what to do to fix it.</s>

---

Edit:

After playing with the code some more I realized that I was missing part of the code. What I understand is that to get the size the code figures out how much has already been read, adjusts the pointer to that position and then calculates how much is left and returns that value. But since the iostream is new and it was casted .get() returns memory position and passed the if statements. Then the istream part changes the pointer to the very end and that's why the ostream part fails. Is this correct?

Edit 2:
Found the solution. The problem is in myIstream->seekg(oldPos) but because the state is shared between myIstream and myOstream the error is not caught until the ostream call. String buffers are lazily allocated but seekp() does not accommodate this. A work around for this problem is to fill the stringstream with garbage data or better yet to check if it is empty prior to using it.

Comment: `tellp()` returns -1 if `fail()` is true. so clearly the `seekp()` had previously failed. But you are not doing any error handling. For instance, does the `ostream` even have an output file/buffer open before you try to seek it? What kind of buffer is the `iostream` operating on?

Comment: What do you mean by "Iostream that I just created and haven’t initialized yet"? Do you create iostream or some of its derived classes (fstream, stringstream)? How do you not initialize it? Complete code that shows the issue would help.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing part of the code. The iostream is parsed into an istream and an ostream and it manipulates pointers on both streams to determine the size. Without the istream the code works, so I am guessing  the istream part changes the pointer to the very end and that's why the ostream part fails. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Self-answers are encouraged here, but we ask that they be posted as an actual answer rather than as an edit to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem is in myIstream->seekg(oldPos) but because the state is shared between myIstream and myOstream the error is not caught until the ostream call. String buffers are lazily allocated but seekp() does not accommodate this. A work around for this problem is to fill the stringstream with garbage data or better yet to check if it is empty prior to using it. – Namox9001